# Xcode debugging is slow!

Tags: iphone, xcode, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to debug an Unity3D iPhone app using Xcode and it's ultra slow.

The application is running smoothly but the Xcode environment crawls to a halt. I can barely get to the debug menu and turn terminate it. I'm running this on a 2GHz, 3GB RAM machine, and Xcode isn't even hogging any cpu in the activity monitor. Any ideas to what might be causing this?

Regards/Per

Answer (score 1):

As jonas echterhoff [states on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7603/how-would-i-debug-a-unity-plugin-from-xcode.html):

> I haven't tried this for Unity C++ plugins, but this is normally how
>   you debug dynamic libraries in XCode (works with our web plugin):
>
> Build a debug version of your plugin. Then either: -Run Unity, in
>   XCode "Run" menu choose "Attach to Process" to attach to Unity -Or
>   choose "Project"->"New Custom Executable", Choose Unity.app, set the
>   working directory to Unity, and then run that executable from XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is not technical but from my experience it works perfectly fine. While debugging, if it is slow click on one of .xib file. By doing this, building will be fast.